# Issue OracleCommand with Parameters.Add

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

Good morning,

I'm migrating a vb to c# app using oracle as a db, im getting the following issue when im add the third parameter in the "add" method

im doing like this in vb: here it works fine

```
 Public Function Tamanio() As Integer
            Dim IntTamanio As Integer = 0
            Select Case IntTipo
                Case OracleType.DateTime Or OracleType.Double Or _
                     OracleType.Float Or OracleType.Int16 Or _
                     OracleType.Int32 Or OracleType.Number : IntTamanio = 0
                Case Else : IntTamanio = StrValor.Length
            End Select
            Return IntTamanio
        End Function



 Private Sub CrearParametros(ByVal PSqlCmd As OracleCommand, ByVal Parametros As List(Of TParametro))
        Try
            For Each Parametro As TParametro In Parametros
                PSqlCmd.Parameters.Add(Parametro.Nombre, Parametro.TipoDato, Parametro.Tamanio).Value = Parametro.Valor
                    PSqlCmd.CreateParameter()
            Next
            PSqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PCodigo", OracleType.Int16, 0, 1).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            PSqlCmd.CreateParameter()
            PSqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PMensaje", OracleType.VarChar, 250, Nothing).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            PSqlCmd.CreateParameter()
            PSqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PRs", OracleType.Cursor, 0, Nothing).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            PSqlCmd.CreateParameter()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

But when i do the same in C#: here is where i get the error

```
public int Tamanio()
            {
                int IntTamanio = 0;
                switch (IntTipo)
                {
                    case OracleType.DateTime | OracleType.Double | OracleType.Float | OracleType.Int16 | OracleType.Int32 |             OracleType.Number:
                        IntTamanio = 0;
                        break;
                    default:
                        IntTamanio = StrValor.Length;
                        break;
                }
                return IntTamanio;
            }

private void CrearParametros(OracleCommand PSqlCmd, List<TParametro> Parametros)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (TParametro Parametro in Parametros)
                {
                    PSqlCmd.Parameters.Add(Parametro.Nombre,Parametro.TipoDato, Parametro.Tamanio).Value = Parametro.Valor;
                    PSqlCmd.CreateParameter();
                }
                PSqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PCodigo", OracleType.Int16, 0, null).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                PSqlCmd.CreateParameter();
                PSqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PMensaje", OracleType.VarChar, 250, null).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                PSqlCmd.CreateParameter();
                PSqlCmd.Parameters.Add("PRs", OracleType.Cursor, 0, null).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                PSqlCmd.CreateParameter();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

the error says: The best coincidence of overloads for

> "System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameterCollection.Add(string,System.Data.OracleClient,int)"
>   have few invalid arguments.

Does anyone know what could possibly happen?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using a valid method signature? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What are the types of `Parametro.Nombre`, `Parametro.TipoDato` and `Parametro.Tamanio`? Clearly it doesn't match with `string, System.Data.OracleClient, int` signature of this method.